# How do I deploy own server (written in Java) on AWS (something like Openshift's DIY)?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, deployment, go, rpc

Is there some thing similar to "**Openshift's DIY**" on **AWS**?
I never use AWS, now need deploy our team's own server(written java) on cloud, and we must use AWS.
This server listening to a custom port, and offering RPC service for client.

I wonder whether it is possible to do DIY on AWS, and how? 
And whether that supports **go language** server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenShift is a PaaS provider. It gives you a ***P**latform* with a Java runtime and an application server (Tomcat, Wildfly,...) on which you can deploy your application.

AWS has a lot of different services. EC2 is a IaaS. It gives you an ***I**nfrastructure*. It starts a virtual machine with the operating system you've choosen, then you install Java and you can deploy your application. Some additional setup has to be done on the virtual network.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Linux server instances can run Go applications just like any other Linux server. You won't get anything like Google App Engine of course. You'll just get a bare Linux server.